# Usage of xml.evaluate in XPath

Tags: javascript, xml, xpath

http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryit.asp?filename=try_xpath_select_cdnodes
Hi, This is the link to the original example. I also copy pasted the code here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        showResult(xhttp.responseXML);
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "books.xml", true);
xhttp.send(); 

function showResult(xml) {
    var txt = "";
    path = "/bookstore/book/title"
    if (xml.evaluate) {                 // what is this line of code for?
        var nodes = xml.evaluate(path, xml, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
        var result = nodes.iterateNext();
        while (result) {
            txt += result.childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br>";
            result = nodes.iterateNext();
        } 
    // Code For Internet Explorer
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject || xhttp.responseType == "msxml-document") {
        xml.setProperty("SelectionLanguage", "XPath");
        nodes = xml.selectNodes(path);
        for (i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
            txt += nodes[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br>";
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I don't understand the purpose of the `if(xml.evaluate)` statement.
It looks like it is testing browser support for XPath, but it also looks like it is testing whether `xml.evaluate` returns true or false.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

"if (xml.evaluate)" line is used to check the browser type.

If the browser type is Chrome, Firefox, Opera, etc... the codes within the "if (xml.evaluate)" function will be executed.

Only when the browser is Internet Explorer, the codes within the "if(window.ActiveXObject || xhttp.responseType == "msxml-document")" will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

It serves two purposes:

- As a guard for null values (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseXML)
- To prevent compatibility issues because of IE (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate , section Browser compatibility)

Looking for these documentation, I've reached https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript that looks promising to understand it further.

Comment: thanks. I have a fair understanding about evaluate() as a function, as discussed in your third link. What I don't understand is the usage inside the if statement.

Comment: I don't know whether "evaluate" in if (xml.evaluate) is a function or object property, or specifically what is being evaluated for this if statement.

Comment: As you don't use the parentheses, it returns the "definition" of the function instead of its execution. In that way is useful to prevent compatibility issues (see 2nd bullet).